# Asynchronus javascript service call to reduce turn around time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a scenario in an enterprise application which is partially based on angular js. We have some ReSTful service to access data from different domain. The problem is that when the service fails the server side cannot posibly know the reason of failure as it is happening on client side (browser).

The possible solution to the problem will be that in the error block make a service call to server to log the response received from the third party service. But if I do that it will increase the turn around time for given service call which in turn result in slower user experience.

My thought on this is to implement some asynchronus queue which sends the service failure periodically to server. Could any one suggest the how to achive the same using javascript?

Comment: cannot even understand what you mean. Please add some pictures / schemas or explain it in more understandable way. Also add the code you tried / want to try / work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement an pinging AJAX call to your server sending the required data of service failure.

you can create an cache for the data the you need to communicate to server and clear it when you do a successful ping AJAX.

you can select any conformable time interval based on application performance for ping interval duration.